# How can I visually select a regex match?

Tags: regular-expression, visual-mode

Sometimes I just want to see whether a regex is matching the right stuff. If I could cause Vim to visually select the matching text, it would be one way to do this. Is there a method for doing this?

Comment: Have you tried eg `incsearch`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Vim will use a colour for search matches if you have the `'hlsearch'` option switched on:

```
:set hlsearch
```

You can then just search for your regular expression and see if it is highlighted:

```
/regex
```

Note that, if you also have `'incsearch'` set, Vim will begin highlighting matches as soon as you start typing in your regular expression: with that option disabled the highlighting won't occur until you execute the search by pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

The `Search` highlighting group is used for highlighting. You can check how this group is configured with the command:

```
:highlight Search
```

When you are done, you can remove the highlighting with the command:

```
:nohlsearch
```

Note the difference between this and `:set nohlsearch`, which turns off search highlighting entirely: the `:nohlsearch` command leaves the `hlsearch` option *on*, and will only turn off highlighting until the next time you search.

See `:help 'hlsearch'` for more details.

Comment: for visually selecting a regex, the `gn` command has been added

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt As far as I can tell from the question and later comment, by "visually select" the OP means "highlight", rather than "make a visual-mode selection". (The OP has already rejected an answer suggesting `gn`, and I don't understand what is meant by the first sentence of the question if the OP really means "make a visual-mode selection").

Answer (score 4):

This can be achieved with `gn`.

See [`:h gn`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/visual.txt.html#gn) for details.

Comment: I know how to not match. The problem is how to activate the visual selection.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. `gn` activates the visual selection here (for the next match)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `:g/<pattern>/y` to yank matches or `:v/<pattern>/y` to yank on no match, I believe.

Comment: Beware that this will run the `:yank` command once for each line that matches, so you will only have the last matching line in the register (unless you specify an uppercase letter like `:global/…/yank A`).

Comment: Also that doesn't really answer the question: OP wanted to visually check their regex, your command would just yank a line (lines with Ben's fix) without visual feedback.